# Is there an XML sitemap generator with command line interface for nginx on Linux?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, seo-software

I'm looking for an **XML sitemap generator** that can be triggered from the **command line**, supports **nginx**, and works on **Linux** (Debian). What can you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you trying Google'ing this? First result on the first page:

https://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

Edit:

As per the comments, I tried out the following sitemap generator:

http://sitemap-generators.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/en/sitemap-generator.html

The downloaded zip bundle contains a few files:

```
drwxr-xr-x  19 user  group     646 Apr 10 05:22 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  group     102 Apr 10 05:12 ..
-r--r-----@  1 user  group      23 Jun 16  2005 AUTHORS
-r--r-----@  1 user  group    1791 Jun 16  2005 COPYING
-r--r--r--@  1 user  group    2267 Dec  5  2005 ChangeLog
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  group     258 Dec  5  2005 PKG-INFO
-r--r--r--@  1 user  group    1111 Dec  5  2005 README
drwxr-xr-x   3 user  group     102 Apr 10 05:16 build
-r--r--r--@  1 user  group    5662 Sep  7  2005 example_config.xml
-r--r-----@  1 user  group     996 Jun 16  2005 example_urllist.txt
-r-xr-xr-x@  1 user  group     317 Dec  5  2005 setup.py
-r-xr-xr-x@  1 user  group   73063 Dec  5  2005 sitemap_gen.py
-r-xr-xr-x@  1 user  group   28551 Sep  7  2005 test_sitemap_gen.py
```

Using the provided example_config.xml, I modified it in the following manner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<site
  base_url="http://YOURDOMAIN.com/"
  store_into="/var/www/sitemap_gen-1.4/sitemap.xml"
  verbose="1"
  >

  <url  href="http://YOURDOMAIN.com/stats?q=name"  />
  <url
     href="http://YOURDOMAIN.com/stats?q=age"
     lastmod="2004-11-14T01:00:00-07:00"
     changefreq="yearly"
     priority="0.3"
  />


  <urllist  path="urllist.txt"  encoding="UTF-8"  />

  <!-- Exclude URLs that end with a '~'   (IE: emacs backup files)      -->
  <filter  action="drop"  type="wildcard"  pattern="*~"           />

  <!-- Exclude URLs within UNIX-style hidden files or directories       -->
  <filter  action="drop"  type="regexp"    pattern="/\.[^/]*"     />

</site>
```

I think that serves as the template for generating the sitemap.xml.  Now, the generator supports pulling URLS from apache style access logs or pulling from a url list file. I opted to pull from a url list file, since I was testing from my laptop.

To generate the url list, I employed 'wget' to spider the site:

```
wget -mk --spider -r -l2 http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/
```

or

```
wget -mk --spider -r -l2 http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/ -o urlinfolist.txt
```

`-r`: recursive; `-l2`: depth (if not set, depth = unlimited). See [`wget` manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options).

Then extracted the URLS from the wget-log that is generated:

```
cat wget-log | tr ' ' '\012' | grep "^http" | egrep -vi "[?]|[.]jpg$" | sort -u > urllist.txt
```

or

```
cat urlinfolist.txt | tr ' ' '\012' | grep "^http" | egrep -vi "[?]|[.]jpg$" | sort -u > urllist.txt
```

Note: Some of the exclusions I had in my line were not needed because the config file either already excluded them or could very easily exclude them.

Then, ran the generator:

```
python sitemap_gen.py --config=example_config.xml
```

Which produced the sitemap.xml file.

The script looks to be designed to run in an automated fashion. But it worked for my test run. The wget can take a while to run. However, if you don't have any special rewrites/etc, you can just scan your site's static content path with a 'find' and maybe do some filtering on it before dumping it into the url list file.

Comment: @ Wing Tang Wong: Yes I did. I've also tried this generator out, but it [doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905665/getting-google-sitemap-generator-working-error-when-attempting-to-access-you) for me.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting, I tried the Google Python sitemap generator and it worked for me. I'll update my Answer with how I got it to work for me.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much for the explanation and a great example!